# Why the Makefile doesn't work like this?

Tags: gcc

I am learning a tutorial of makefile at [there](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).
For Makefile 2, there is the right codes:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
     $(CC) -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
```

Why it doesn't work like this:

```
hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
    gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
```

and below is the error:

```
hellomake.c:2:10: error: 'hellomake.h' file not found with <angled> include; use
      "quotes" instead
#include <hellomake.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
         "hellomake.h"
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first "working" makefile you use

```
CFLAGS=-I.
```

That will be used when compiling the source files into object files, and tells the compiler (and its preporcessor) that the current directory should be added to the list of system header file directories.

The second makefile doesn't do that. The compiler, when creating the object files, have no extra flags. So the compiler will not add the current directory to the directory list.

The `-I` option you have in the second makefile is when *linking*. By that time the object files have already been created (should have been created if there was no errors), and the `-I` flag is not used at all by the linker.

Comment: Just know `CFLAGS` is a pre-defined macro.